# Orthogonal decomposition of the periodic space $L^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Let $L>0$ and define the space
$$
L^2_{per}([0,L]):=\big\{ f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \; ; \; f  \: \text{is periodic with period $L>0$ and} f|_{[0,L]} \in L^2([0,L]) \big\}.
$$
The space $L^2_{per}([0,L])=L^2_{per}$ is a Hibert space with the inner product
$$
(f,g)_{L^2}=\int_0^L f(x)g(x) \;dx,\; \forall \; f,g \in L^2_{per}.
$$

Also define,
$$
L^2_{o}:=\{ f \in L^2_{per} \; ; \; f \: \text{is a odd function}\} \quad \text{and} \quad L^2_{e}:=\{ f \in L^2_{per} \; ; \; f \: \text{is a even function}\}.
$$

Clearly, $L^2_{o}, L^2_{e} \subset L^2_{per}$ are closed subspaces and hence are Hilbert spaces endowed with the inner product $(\cdot, \cdot)_{L^2}$.

**Question.** If $f \in L^2_{o}$ and $g \in L^2_{e}$, then $(f,g)_{L^2}=0$ ? If so, can I write the orthogonal decomposition $L^2_{per}=L^2_{o} \oplus  L^2_{e}$? Here, the symbol  $\oplus$ means 'direct sum'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The space of $L^2([0,L])$ functions can be represented as fourier series expansion and hence
$$\left\{1,\cos\left(\frac{2\pi nx}{L}\right),\sin\left(\frac{2\pi nx}{L}\right)\; ; \; n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$$ is an orthonormal basis. Consequentely, the odd functions are spanned by
$$\left\{\sin\left(\frac{2\pi nx}{L}\right)\; ; \; n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$$ and even functions are spanned by
$$\left\{1,\cos\left(\frac{2\pi nx}{L}\right)\; ; \; n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}$$ and thus can be written as the direct sum mentioned.

See Theorem $1.3$ in [here](http://math.iisc.ernet.in/%7Eveluma/fourier.pdf).

Comment: because the basis spanning odd and even functions are orthonormal to each other and the whole space is written as sum of these basis put together by fourier series expansion.

Comment: Great answer. Thank you very much!